# Why can a class be called from within another class?

Tags: python, oop

Hi I'm not sure if I've used the right terminology, but I've been assigned a homework for OOP in Python. We have to make a basket system that users can add items to etc... I've completed the homework but I can't figure out why something that I did worked.

I have two classes, Basket() and Shop(). But in the checkout function in Basket, I've used Shop.getPrice(Shop, x). For the life of me I can't figure out why this works.

Also please ignore the sheer number of comments, I had to explain my code to someone.

Thank you in advance

```
class Shop():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = {"eggs":1.95, "bread":0.5, "cheese":2.45}

    def addItem(self, item, price):
        item = item.lower() #? lower case
        self.items[item] = price #? add item to dictionary with price

    def deleteItem(self, item):
        if item in self.items:
            self.items.pop(item) #? remove item from dictionary
        else:
            print("Item not found") #? item not found

    def getPrice(self, item):
        return self.items[item] #? returns the price of item

    #! DONT LOOK AT THIS FUNCTION
    def changePrice(self, item, newPrice):
        if newPrice > 0:
            self.items.update({item:newPrice})
        else:
            print("Price must be greater than 0")

    def getInput(self): 
        choice = int(input("""
        1. Display Basket
        2. Select Item
        3. Checkout
        4. Exit
        Please enter your choice: """))
        return choice #? return the input

    def main(self):
        running = True
        basket = Basket() #? instantiate basket
        while running:
            choice = shop.getInput() #? get input from user
            if choice == 1:
                basket.showBasket() #? show basket
            elif choice == 2:
                #! Select Item
                found = False #? sets up loop
                while not(found): #? loop until item is found
                    choice = input("Enter the name of the item: ")
                    choice.lower()
                    if choice in shop.items: #? checks if item is in shop
                        basket.addToBasket(choice) #? add item to basket
                        found = True #? exit loop
                    else:
                        print("Item not found, please try again")
            elif choice == 3:
                #! Checkout
                basket.checkout() #? run checkout function
            elif choice == 4:
                #! Exit
                running = False #? exit loop
            else:
                print("Invalid choice")

shop = Shop()

class Basket():
    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = {} #? basket is empty to begin with
    
    def addToBasket(self, item):
        if item in self.contents: #? if item is in basket, add 1 to quantity
            self.contents[item] += 1
        else:  #? if item is not in basket, add item to basket
            self.contents[item] = 1


    def removeFromBasket(self, item):
        if item in self.contents:
            if self.contents[item] > 1: #? if item is more than 1, remove 1
                self.contents[item] -= 1
            else: #? else remove item
                self.contents.pop(item)
        else:
            print("Item not found")

    def checkout(self):
        total = 0
        for x in self.contents:
            total += self.contents[x] * Shop.getPrice(Shop, x)
        print("Total: " + str(total))

    def showBasket(self):
        for x in self.contents:
            print(self.contents[x])

shop.main()
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why is `main` a method of the `Shop` class? And since it is, you should use `self` to refer to the `Shop` object inside `main`.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you be able to call one class from another? I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually work...? The line you're wondering about throws an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Your code doesn't work (`AttributeError: type object 'Shop' has no attribute 'items'`). Did you mean `Shop.getPrice(shop, x)`? (Notice the argument is the _object_, not the _class_). This works because that's how methods work behind the scenes: Calling `shop.some_method()` is the same as calling `Shop.some_method(shop)`. A decent Python OOP tutorial will cover this.

Comment: It should be `shop.getPrice(x)`. You need to understand the difference between the class and an instance.

Answer (score -2):

Your function Shop.getPrice(Shop, x), worked because you have the classes in the same file, and Shop() class it's in the scope of Basket() class

Comment: But it _doesn't_ work because `Shop` is a type and the type doesn't have an attribute `items` when you go into `getPrice` and try to do `Shop.items[...]`